# VSO/VSTS and MBCS

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, mbcs

I have an old VS2013 solution (20s C++ and C# projects) that need to be migrate to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).  Unfortunately, some of the projects use mutibyte character set (MBCS).  I used VSTS hosted build, but it failed with the error below:

```
Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library.
```

Changing to Unicode will require modifying a whole bunch of projects (and some dll/lib that we don't event have the source code) and so is not very feasible.
I just wonder is there any way to add MBCS support to the build process?

Comment: Can you build it through command line manually on local machine? I made a test with MFC project that set MBCS (VS 2015 not VS2013), it works fine on Hosted agent. What's the result if you upgrade project to 2015? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Sorry for a very late response.  MBCS is supported by default in VS 2015 and later.  I guess MS got plenty of complains after making it an addon in vs 2013.  We could not find any solution, and decided to "solve" the problem by upgrading the code to vs 2017.